# Attaching a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like

```
a = [{name: 'x', 'hour':35, 'unit': 500},
     {name: 'y', 'hour': 40, 'unit': 600},
     {name: 'z', 'hour': 50, 'unit': 700},
     {name: 'z', 'hour': 20, 'unit': 400},
     {name: 'x', 'hour': 40, 'unit': 500}]
```

and a second dictionary like

```
b = {'z': 200, 'y': 100, 'x': 50}
```

Is there any way i could assign 2nd dictionary to first one so that I could produce result like

```
a = [{name: 'x', 'hour':35, 'unit': 500, 'b': 50},
     {name: 'y', 'hour': 40, 'unit': 600, 'b': 100},
     {name: 'z', 'hour': 50, 'unit': 700, 'b': 200},
     {name: 'z', 'hour': 20, 'unit': 400, 'b': 200},
     {name: 'x', 'hour': 40, 'unit': 500, 'b': 50}]
```

or at-least a list like

```
[50, 100, 200, 200, 50]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following approach:

```
>>> for sub in a:
...    sub['b'] = b.get(sub['name'], None)
... 
>>> a
[{'unit': 500, 'b': 50, 'name': 'x', 'hour': 35},
 {'unit': 600, 'b': 100, 'name': 'y', 'hour': 40},
 {'unit': 700, 'b': 200, 'name': 'z', 'hour': 50},
 {'unit': 400, 'b': 200, 'name': 'z', 'hour': 20},
 {'unit': 500, 'b': 50, 'name': 'x', 'hour': 40}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kasramvd answered your first part. If you want the second part,

```
>>> [b[i['name']] for i in a]
[50, 100, 200, 200, 50]
```